# Find smallest integer greater or equal than x (positive integer) multiple of z (positive integer, probably power of 2)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Probably very easy question, yet I came out with this implementation that looks far too complicated...

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int z;
unsigned int makeXMultipleOfZ(const unsigned x, const unsigned z) {
    return x + (z - x % z) % z;
    //or
    //return x + (z - (x + 1) % z - 1); //This generates shorter assembly, 
                                        //6 against 8 instructions
}
```

- I would like to avoid if-statements
- If this can help we can safely say that z will be a power of 2

In my case `z=4` (I know I could replace the modulo operation with a `&` bit operator), and I was wondering if could come with an implementation that involves less steps.

Comment: how many steps do you think are involved? Also, this is rounding.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid if-statements and why do you think the way you did it is 'way too complicated'?

Comment: I could not really find this subject discussed anywhere, and it seems such a simple operation that I would have expected a faster implementation could exist. @Dukeling conditional statements makes code more slow.

Comment: @Antonio Yes, it does exist. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Antonio Not using a conditional statement here would be a micro-optimization, i.e. something that, while in theory might be a little faster, doesn't make a significant enough difference to be noticeable in basically all real-world scenario's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `z` is a power of two, the modulo operation can be reduced to this bitwise  operation:

`return (x + z - 1) & ~(z - 1);`

This logic is very common for data structure boundary alignment, for example. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Exactly! Memory alignment is my problem! There's also an interesting comment by Eric Postpischil above, anyway my `z` is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If z is a power of two and the integers are unsigned, the following will work:

```
x + (z - 1) & ~(z - 1)
```

I cannot think of a solution using bit-twiddling if z is an arbitrary number.

Comment: `~(z-1)` is `-z` (for unsigned or two’s complement). Although the optimizer might eliminate the second instance as a common subexpression anyway.

Comment: @MadScientist I think the way you are put parenthesis is confusing: Anyway the `&` is the last operation to be executed. If it was not like that, your solution would be not correct.